# Vibrating string and damping

Tags: waves, string, vibrations, dissipation, normal-modes

Suppose we have a string (in tension) with its ends fixed. Think of a guitar string. Suppose we start with a plucked initial position and we let the string free. If we use the wave equation: $u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx}$ to predict the motion, then d'Alembert's solution is [this](https://youtu.be/PztIiwPSeAU).

In reality, when we pluck a guitar string, the motion we observe is definitely not this one. There is vibration but it is qualitatively very different from our solution. It looks like the first harmonic, and there are no sharp corners. Why does this happen? As I explain towards the end, the justification that I find on the internet is wrong.

First, here is my partial understanding. *At the very beginning* of the motion, our prediction (d'Alembert) will be correct. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_X72on6CSL0&t=29s) for a slow-motion demonstration. There is also [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNNQvG0jWtw&t=24s) for an actual guitar string.

The reason that the motion changes with time is energy-loss. I can think of three mechanisms for this: air resistance, internal friction, and transmission of energy to the rest of the guitar-body. Outside of air resistance, I am not aware of models for the other mechanisms, to incorporate to the wave equation. As I explain below, air resistance alone cannot explain our observation.

Wrong explanation: Looking around the internet I often saw the explanation "higher frequencies attenuate faster". The usual argument is that if we add a damping term $u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx}-\rho u_t$ (air resistance), then higher velocities (caused by higher frequencies) lead to larger damping forces, and thus to faster attenuation. This argument is wrong. [Here](http://www.uwosh.edu/faculty_staff/zhang/fall04/376HW/AnsSec4_3.pdf) is the solution of the last equation. All frequencies decay with the exact same rate: $e^{-\frac{\rho}{2}t}$. This is expected, since in the simple harmonic oscillator with damping, the exponential decay term is independent of the natural frequency.

Comment: Do all frequencies propagate at the same speed? If so, the relative phases would change. A sharp peak can be lost that way. All frequencies at equal amplitude with the right phases add up to a delta function. Without random phases, they add to white noise.

Comment: Here's a video that shows the first 38 or so cycles\* of vibration of a plucked guitar string in slow motion. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNNQvG0jWtw The sharp corners are obvious at the start, but they soon become more rounded, although the overall shape of the wave remains roughly the same. I would _guess_ that agrees with "the usual argument" about the higher frequency components of the wave being damped more quickly than the lower frequency components. \[\*38 cycles of the open D string should take about 1/4 second if the guitar is properly tuned.]

Comment: ...If "this argument is wrong," then maybe the problem is that the equation you showed is not an adequate model of the reality.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Thanks for answering! The link you posted was also given at my question. I am not saying that the claim "higher frequencies attenuate faster is wrong." I am only saying that whenever I find a justification for this claim is via this equation. Thus, this particular justification is wrong. I am looking for a correct justification.